# Cannot clone with Bonobo Git server hosted on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7)

Tags: git, iis, bonobo

I have installed Bonobo 3.4.3, following the instructions [here](http://bonobogitserver.com/install/). I am able to access the site, add a repository, users, etc. I created a repository to test pushing/pulling with, named Test, and then tried to clone it and that's when my issue arose. I have git 1.9.5.msysgit.0 installed on Windows 7; I opened a git bash session in the directory I wanted to clone the repository to and issued:

```
git clone http://localhost/Bonobo/Test.git
```

And received the error:

```
fatal: http://localhost/Bonobo/Test.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I have tried a lot of different things, to no avail:

- Using Basic Auth
- Using Windows Auth
- Re-installing git
- Re-installing Bonobo
- Creating a repository and trying to add the server as a remote

Now here's the real kicker: I have another Windows 7 machine that I decided to try this on - followed same installation process, made sure my msysgit was up to date (they're the same version now), created the Test repository, popped open git bash and issued the same clone command - **and it worked**. I have yet to figure out what the difference is between the installations.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit #1:**

I created a new repository on both of the Windows machines named "Test2", copied each to a flash drive with a machine identifier (e.g. DELL) appended to the folder name, and then diff'd them:

```
diff -bur Test2-DELL/ Test2-THINKPAD/
```

And there were no differences. So, the issue does not lie within the repository creation on Bonobo's part. Will update when I try other things.

**Edit 2:**

I opened HTTP traffic (in) on the computer with the working Bonobo server and was able to clone the Test repository from it on to the computer with the non-working Bonobo server which implies to me that there is still something wrong with my actual install of Bonobo on the non-working computer.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to resolve the issue? I have similar problem - can't git clone on my machine while it works on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it was a credential issue. In the command line I changed my git credentials using

```
git config --global user.name = "myusername"
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be setting `user.name` twice for the username and password?